# How to setup a Postfix SMTP-only for multiple domains

Tags: postfix, smtp

This is my first question on Stacks. I always read a lot of solutions to problems here almost every other day. So thank you to all contributors. I am a noob here so please spare some space  if I am doing something wrong. My question is

I am trying to setup a Postfix server to be an SMTP only host for multiple domain names. I do not allow remote connection I just want to be able to use my cron scripts to send emails for various domains. Currently Postfix is default installation but I have added

```
 myhostname=example.com
```

Now problem is if I send email from email@example2.com the host shown in email headers (not in From address) is example.com the exact header is

```
Received: from example.com
```

my from address is correct. Pardon me but I really don't know a lot about email servers. My incoming is handled by another hosting provider and I know I need to add a reverse dns etc. So please if anyone knows what I should do so all domains have right DNS entries plus good postfix configuration. I want postfix to use the same domain name as the from address. I only need smtp and nothing else.

I have searched google and Stacks but none answered the question completely even if the question was similar.

Thanks in advance, I am still RTFMing all over the place.

I am also getting these errors in my mailog. i have replaced a real valid domain name with MYDOMAIN and a real system username with USER

```
Feb 14 22:53:13 li222-89 postfix/smtpd[28433]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Feb 14 22:53:13 li222-89 postfix/smtpd[28433]: 428FCA400C: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Feb 14 22:53:13 li222-89 postfix/cleanup[28436]: 428FCA400C: message-id=<4d59f8a8-0ab4-4aee-b6e6-6f0c9389ad7c@>
Feb 14 22:53:13 li222-89 postfix/qmgr[27293]: 428FCA400C: from=<noreply@MYDOMAIN.net>, size=1047, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 14 22:53:13 li222-89 postfix/smtpd[28433]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Feb 14 22:53:13 li222-89 postfix/smtp[27755]: certificate verification failed for gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com: num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
Feb 14 22:53:13 li222-89 postfix/smtp[27755]: certificate verification failed for gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com: num=27:certificate not trusted
Feb 14 22:53:13 li222-89 postfix/pickup[26953]: C3761A400D: uid=500 from=<USER>
Feb 14 22:53:13 li222-89 postfix/cleanup[28436]: C3761A400D: message-id=<20110215035313.C3761A400D@example.net>
Feb 14 22:53:13 li222-89 postfix/qmgr[27293]: C3761A400D: from=<USER@net.net>, size=3237, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 14 22:53:14 li222-89 postfix/smtp[26830]: certificate verification failed for aspmx.l.google.com: num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
Feb 14 22:53:14 li222-89 postfix/smtp[26830]: certificate verification failed for aspmx.l.google.com: num=27:certificate not trusted
Feb 14 22:53:15 li222-89 postfix/smtp[27755]: 428FCA400C: to=<somebodysomebody@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.155.27]:25, delay=2.6, delays=0.02/0.02/0.66/1.9, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1297741995 l9si6487318yhl.10)
Feb 14 22:53:15 li222-89 postfix/qmgr[27293]: 428FCA400C: removed
Feb 14 22:53:17 li222-89 postfix/smtp[26830]: C3761A400D: to=<USER@net.net>, orig_to=<USER>, relay=aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.155.27]:25, delay=14, delays=11/0/0.44/3.1, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.155.27] said: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at                              550 5.1.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 hj39si8560308ibb.50 (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Feb 14 22:53:17 li222-89 postfix/cleanup[28436]: 726DFA400C: message-id=<20110215035317.726DFA400C@example.net>
Feb 14 22:53:17 li222-89 postfix/qmgr[27293]: 726DFA400C: from=<>, size=5596, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 14 22:53:17 li222-89 postfix/bounce[28222]: C3761A400D: sender non-delivery notification: 726DFA400C
Feb 14 22:53:17 li222-89 postfix/qmgr[27293]: C3761A400D: removed
Feb 14 22:53:17 li222-89 postfix/smtp[27755]: certificate verification failed for aspmx.l.google.com: num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
Feb 14 22:53:17 li222-89 postfix/smtp[27755]: certificate verification failed for aspmx.l.google.com: num=27:certificate not trusted
Feb 14 22:53:21 li222-89 postfix/smtp[27755]: 726DFA400C: to=<USER@net.net>, relay=aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.155.27]:25, delay=3.6, delays=0.02/0.01/0.44/3.1, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.155.27] said: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at                              550 5.1.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 mu18si8573893ibb.7 (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Feb 14 22:53:21 li222-89 postfix/qmgr[27293]: 726DFA400C: removed
```

Obviously its trying to send email to a gmail account but something is wrong ...really wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you want.

http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#generic

Example:

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:
    smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic

/etc/postfix/generic:
    his@localdomain.local       hisaccount@hisisp.example
    her@localdomain.local       heraccount@herisp.example
    @localdomain.local          hisaccount+local@hisisp.example
```

So, if you have postfix installed and configured already.

Open main.cf and add the generic maps setting above.

Then open the generic file and add @example.com   @example2.com or whatever settings you need for your environment

This is a hash file so when you are done run `postmap /etc/postfix/generic`

Then restart postfix.

**UPDATE**

It looks like this is actually what you are after.

edit the master cf file and change this line

```
smtp inet n - n - - smtpd
```

To:

```
localhost:smtp  inet n - n - - smtpd
ipaddress1:smtp inet n - n - - smtpd
ipaddress2:smtp inet n - n - - smtpd -o myhostname=hostname2
.
.
.
ipaddressn:smtp inet n - n - - smtpd -o myhostname=hostname3
```

restart postfix

Obviously this will require you to setup multiple IP address, one for each domain and setting up the reverse DNS etc.  I believe this is the only way to do this.

Comment: thanks. Ill give this a try. also i check my logs I get weird errors. I updated my post

Comment: hey pablo, thanks for reply but this isnt what I am looking for. I can send ok using localhost smtp and the from adress is example1.com but I still get my hostname (default domain example.com) in the email headers.

Comment: could you send over an example header so I could have a look?

Comment: hey pablo. i have only one IP. but its ok I think your solution would work one way or another, just needs more RTFM. a newbie like me would probably mess it up. I accept your as a valid solution unless someone has a better idea. thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 3):

```
Feb 14 22:53:17 li222-89 postfix/smtp[27755]: certificate verification failed for aspmx.l.google.com: num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
Feb 14 22:53:17 li222-89 postfix/smtp[27755]: certificate verification failed for aspmx.l.google.com: num=27:certificate not trusted
```

If you're attempting to relay mail using Gmail, then it will be necessary to use TLS with Postfix.First, double-check that Postfix was configured with SSL support (ie. ldd should return at least one line starting with libssl):

```
$ whereis -b postfix
postfix: /usr/sbin/postfix /etc/postfix /usr/libexec/postfix
$ ldd /usr/sbin/postfix
...
libssl.so.6 => /lib/libssl.so.6 (0x00111000)
...
```

Now we need to find your server's CA root certificate bundle, which is typically distributed with openssl.

```
$ locate ca-bundle.crt
/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Edit the Postfix main.cf to include TLS and SASL2 for Gmail authentication.

[Update your certificate file](https://calomel.org/postfix.html) with new Gmail certificate provider.

```
relayhost = smtp.gmail.com:587

# your FQDN, or default value below
mydomain = example.com

# your local machine name, or default value below
myhostname = host.example.com
myorigin = $myhostname

# SASL
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_type = cyrus
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

# TLS
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_use_tls  = yes
smtp_tls_CAfile = /path/to/your/ca-bundle.crt
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
```

[Postfix config "how to" ( main.cf )](https://calomel.org/postfix.html)

[Setup Postfix with a remote SMTP relay host](http://www.zulius.com/how-to/set-up-postfix-with-a-remote-smtp-relay-host/)

Comment: Your answer came later but I add a note why I think its not correct for my question. My problem was not with gmail , the problem is with email headers not correctly using the domain I am sending from. Also I need to send from multiple domains on the same system. For some reason it just uses hostname.localdomain or the one real domain I manage to specify.

Comment: Actually for Gmail no matter which email headers you set. Gmail needs only correct authentication.